# How do I change the attribute name while using SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say, I have a table Student, with attributes, Name, Grade and Class. Now I want to retrieve a table but the name of the attributes are slightly changed, so that I want the result to view StudentName,Grade and Class.

I am looking for something like

```
SELECT Name is StudentName,Grade, Class from Student
```

Comment: `Name as StudentName`

Comment: Search the Internet for [column alias](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/).

Comment: In RDBS we generally refer to each item in a table as "columns", as opposed to attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `as` to give column an alias name.

```
SELECT Name as StudentName,
       Grade, 
       Class 
from Student
```

[Problems with Column Aliases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)